# Spring Security: How to reject a request by default if no @PreAuthorize was specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot application which exposes a REST API.
I have successfully configured the spring security to secure every method in the rest API according to its ROLE, using the **@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_4')")** annotation.

I have noticed that If I don't put the **@PreAuthorize** annotation at all, the framework allows this request to any authenticated user. I want to reverse this behavior. So if one of the programmers will forget to add the **@PreAuthorize** annotation, any request to this method will be rejected automatically.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //Disable HTTP Basic authentication
    http.httpBasic().disable();

    //Add the filters
    http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(securityServiceAuthenticationProvider());
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider securityServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new SecurityServiceAuthenticationProvider();
}

}
```

Thanks
Guy Hudara

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MethodSecurityInterceptor; sample XML configuration is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#explicit-methodsecurityinterceptor-configuration).  The example applies security to a single bean, but the expressions are very flexible, you can protect e.g. all public members of any class with name ending in "Controller".  I have used a similar XML configuration before, but I haven't done this with Java configuration; but I suppose you can do the same thing in Java configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a custom [AccessDecisionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html#authz-access-decision-manager) and, if the queried object is a `MethodInvocation`, then check if it has a `@PreAuthorize` annotation; if yes, let it pass. Otherwise, fail it. You can add it to the configuration like this: `http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(myManager)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. I used the following confoguration: **.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager()).anyRequest().authenticated();** But I get **FilterInvocation**, and not **MethodInvocation**. I am new to Spring Security, and must admit, that I don't fully understand this framework.